# How to Filter Specific Rows in Excel

Tags: excel

**Hey guys, I have a question regarding formatting rows in excel. Basically, I have a chart with about 6 rows and consisting of pharmaceutical products. There are 4 types of categorization that each product may fall under (I, II, III, IV) in Row C. I want to eliminate all types I, III and IV while retaining all II. How can I perform this action? Thank you in advance. **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Excel sheet perform the below actions:

1. Click on the **top** of your **C** column.
2. Click on **Data** tab on the top.
3. Click on **Filter** option that you will after clicking on **Data**.
4. Now, you will see a symbol (**drop button**) on all the columns. Click on that symbol corresponding to the **C** column.
5. Choose the values(I, III and IV)

Hope this might help. Mark as accepted answer if it works for you. :)